# C implentation of Simon Plouffe's 1996 algorithm for computing pi fails

Tags: c, algorithm, pi

You can see the pi formula in the "approximations of pi" Wikipedia article. I was attracted to the formula because it is compact and promises efficient computation, plus it is specialized for base 10. The formula is

```
 pi = -3 + SUM(n=0,oo): n*(2^n)*(n!)^2/(2*n)!
```

My C code is below. It seems very straight forward. It computes all of the intermediate steps, but it completely fails to converge. What is the bug?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define sq(x)  ((x)*(x))
int nfac(int);
int main()
{
  double term, denom, sum;
  double w, x, y, z, pi;
  int n;

/* Plouffe's 1996 algorithm 
(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_π:  */
  sum = -3.;
  for(n=1; n <= 11; n++)
  {
    printf("n= %d\n", n);
    printf("n! = %.0f\n", w = nfac(n));
    printf("(n!)^2 = %.0f\n", x = sq(w));
    printf("2^n = %.0f\n", y = pow(2,n));
    printf("(2*n)! = %.0f\n", z = nfac(2*n));
    printf("n*2^n)*((n!)^2)/(2*n)! = %f\n", term = n*y*x/z);
    printf("sum = %f\n\n", sum += term);
  }
  printf("pi = %.10f\n\n", pi = sum); 
}

int nfac(int n)
{
  int i, nn;

  if(n==0) return 1;

  nn = 1;
  for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    nn= i*nn;
  return nn;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple! Your `nfac`-method returns an `int`...

During computation you will also call it with arguments like `22` 
(line: `printf("(2*n)! = %.0f\n", z = nfac(2*n));` with `n = 11`).

The result of that does **not** fit inside of an `int` ;)

I would suggest using another type for `nfac`, but as others already suggested, I have no idea how precise your result will get even when using `double`.

Answer (score 0):

A `double` and `int` can only hold a limited number, and if you get into the high ranges of `double` its precision deteriorates. You should really read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

You need a large number library to do this kind of calculation.

---

As an example, let's say you use a 64-bit unsigned integer. What is the maximum factorial that fits in this? The answer is a mere 20!

```
factorial(21)  = 51090942171709440000
pow(2, 64) - 1 = 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: absolutely... especially looking at the fact that with the current 11 iterations it should have a `sum` of just `~3.10046` (assuming no precision problems) while already having huge intermediate values... even if `double` were precise, I'm sure you will even exceed `double`'s maximum value before getting anywhere near 3,14159... ;)